# Installing posh-git in visual studio package manager

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, posh-git

I'm trying to install posh-git to the visual studio package manager console (vs 2012) and I'm getting the following error when running .\install.ps1 in the poshgit directory and reloading the profile:

```
Register-TabExpansion : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Type'.
At D:\posh-git\GitTabExpansion.ps1:218 char:37
+     Register-TabExpansion "git.exe" -Type Command {
+                                     ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Register-TabExpansion], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Register-TabExpansion
```

I can install posh-git from a normal powershell prompt with no issues it only seems to be running into this in vs 2012.

Any idea why I'm getting this error in vs only and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

posh-git tries to integrate with [PowerTab](http://powertab.codeplex.com/), which provides a `Register-TabExpansion` function. It seems NuGet now provides its own function of the same name, but with a different signature. I just pushed a new version of posh-git with a fix.